# CodeIgniter Update not Fully Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to update a mySQL table while using CodeIgniter.

**The Controller**

I have the redirect() commented out to use print_r(). When it returns the array, it returns the correct updated values. But if i uncomment the redirect, then it will redirect me to the page with the table and the values will not get updated. I also check on phpMyAdmin to make sure values arent getting updated and not just displaying, but they arent updating on their either. This is confusing me because the print_r() is returning the correct values.

```
<?php
class update_ctrl extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('update_model');
    }

    public function updateGame($id){
        $this->load->model('update_model');
        $data['games'] = $this->update_model->getGame($id);
        $this->load->view('update_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function update(){
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('genre', 'Genre', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('developer', 'Developer', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'YearReleased', 'trim|required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required|numeric');
        $id = $this->input->post('ID');
        $data = array(
                                'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                                'Genre' => $this->input->post('genre'),
                                'Developer' => $this->input->post('developer'),
                                'YearReleased' => $this->input->post('year'),
                                'Price' => $this->input->post('price')
                        );
            $this->load->model('update_model');
            $this->update_model->update($id, $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Game Updated!');
            print_r($data);
            //redirect('');
        }
    }
?>
```

**The Model**

```
<?php
class update_model extends CI_Model {
    public function getGame($id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('games');
        $this->db->where('ID', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }

    public function update($id, $data){
        $this->db->where('ID', $id);
        $this->db->update('games', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the ID correct?

Comment: Yeah, the id looks like it is correct

Comment: Please screen shot `print_r` the `$data` , `$id` and `var_dump($this->db->last_query())` after updating

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jd1hub

Comment: Var dump the post id make sure you are getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that your query is silently failing. Go into `database.php` and change `db_debug` to `TRUE` and run everything again.

I would also like to add that you seem to do a good job making sure all your fields are validated. I'd also add a validation for `id` just to make sure you are getting it - in the case the user does something funky then they won't get some weird query error because the id wasn't set.

Comment: I have the ID field set to a hidden field, So they cant change it. Do you still think that is necessary?

Comment: You can easily modify a hidden field if you edit it with inspect element. Food for thought.

Comment: Did db debug give you anything useful? an error perhaps...?

Comment: Nothing new came up, Just the same thing happening. Not fully updating in the database for some reason

Comment: Can you post a picture of your db structure/schema for this table?

Comment: If you run the output of `echo $this->db->last_query();` in phpmyadmin does it work?

Comment: Looks fine. Don't see a reason it shouldn't be working. For troubleshooting purposes remove all formvalidation stuff and try again. Then also try my last comment...

Comment: Im confused by what you want me to do in phpMyAdmin. Like type that into the SQL section?

Comment: Copy the **exact** output of `last_query()` into phpmyadmin `sql` tab query/text box and hit "GO"

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes remove all formvalidation stuff and try then. If it's not that, idk what it could be...

Comment: Messing around with it i seemed to fix it.

Comment: I'm curious what exactly you changed because right now it seems like ghosts in the machine

Comment: In my Controller on line 24.

`$id = $this->input->post('ID');`

was changed to 

`$id = $this->input->post('id');`

and now it seems to be working just fine. Do you have any idea to why that was a problem?

Comment: print_r() and $this->db->last_query() gave me the same results as before, but now is actually updating the database. So im confused and wonder if you know why

Comment: That doesn't make any sense because when you echoed it you were getting the variable as shown by your very first screenshot. If that would have changed anything than originally you would have been getting a null value for that... So this only makes me more confused

Comment: I'm thinking maybe your db wasn't refreshing or something. Probably nothing ci related all along and just some weird "thing"

Comment: Can you explain what that did? Because im confused to what actually fixed this. @RyukLee

Answer (score 0):

Comment out your all  `$this->form_validation->set_rules` and try again, I think the numeric validation get errors

```
 public function update(){
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    //$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('genre', 'Genre', 'trim|required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('developer', 'Developer', 'trim|required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'YearReleased', 'trim|required|numeric');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required|numeric');
    $id = $this->input->post('ID');
    $data = array(
                            'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                            'Genre' => $this->input->post('genre'),
                            'Developer' => $this->input->post('developer'),
                            'YearReleased' => $this->input->post('year'),
                            'Price' => $this->input->post('price')
                    );
        $this->load->model('update_model');
        $this->update_model->update($id, $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Game Updated!');
        print_r($data);
        //redirect('');
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly would fv be affecting this if its not being run in the first place ? (atleast for this test). Just curious of your thought process ;)

Comment: Yes but if form validation isn't being run via `run()` in the code how could it be haulting/messing up things?

Comment: Yeah this doesnt seem to do anything either.

Comment: well, try to Put your `$this->db->last_query()` in mysql and excute the query follow the @Alex comment